# Using interpolation between two rows

Tags: matlab, matrix

I am trying to do interpolation. I have a matrix `Y` with `2*1000`. The first row is `Y` values at time `1` sec and the second row is `Y` values at time `3` second. I am trying to get `Y` values at time `1.7` sec

For example,

```
at time 1 sec Y(1,:)=[1 3 4 6 8 1 4 2 9]      and X=[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
at time 3 sec Y(2,:)=[2 6 8 1 9 2 7 8 2]      and X=[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
at time 4 sec Y(3,:)=[21 6 81 1 9 12 7 28 2]  and X=[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
```

I am trying to interpolate with respect to time. I used

```
Y_1_7 = interp1(Y(1,:),Y(2,:),1.7);
```

It is not working

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com seems helpful here

> vq = interp1(x,v,xq) returns interpolated values of a 1-D function at specific query points using linear interpolation.
>
> Vector x contains the **sample points**, and v contains the **corresponding values**, v(x). Vector xq contains the coordinates of the query points.
> If you have multiple sets of data that are sampled at the same point coordinates, then you can pass v as an array. Each column of array v contains a different set of 1-D sample values.

So it should be something like:

```
Y_1_7 = interp1([1 3 4], Y, 1.7)
```

Comment: What does the Y.* syntax here without a second argument do?

Comment: Oops. I meant Y.'   It transposes the Y matrix. It's the same as Y', except in the case of imaginary numbers. In that case, Y' makes transposes, then conjugates all the numbers, whil Y.' just transposes them.

Comment: You broke your code linexpensive with that last edit

Comment: @ Ian Riley, Thank you. Please, can you explain?

Comment: @bwall. Thank you. But I still interpolate for 1.7 which is between row one and two. Why have I to add last time in interpolation?

Comment: You don't from a linear interpolation perspective. However from a programming perspective , because your Y now has 3 columns, interp1( ) function expects there to be 3 times.